# Why are our questions per day going down?

Tags: discussion, statistics, questions

Here are some statistics:

- Over the last 90 days we have had an average of 19 questions per day
- Over the last 30 days we have had an average of 14.8 questions per day
- Over the last 14 days we have had an average of 13.8 questions per day
- Over the last 7 days we have had an average of 14.4 questions per day
- Over the last 2 days we have had an average of 9.5 questions per day

For some reason, I remember this site having 40 questions a day. This is a decrease of nearly 10 questions per day in the last 90 days. Are there any reasons for this? Is this site dying?

Comment: Sampling rate affects frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one reason for the lower number of questions is that Travel is a seasonal activity and thus we end up getting more or less questions depending on the month. Here's a graph plotting the number of questions we get per month over the past 5 years:

[image]

Northern-hemisphere summer months are consistently the most popular and the months of October, November and December are consistently the least popular. So I'd say the situation is close to normal, although the Monica situation might indeed have affected it to an extent.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the normal going up and down we usually have, [the situation with Monica](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/support-of-monica?cb=1) means that a lot of regulars do less or nothing on the site.
It is not as visible on Travel as it is on some other SE sites but it is certainly visible when you see several of the long time regulars not posting much or at all.

Some of the other SE sites only get questions of new users, non of the regulars, and if they do not have many questions from people finding them on search sites, they look dead in the water now.

Comment: This! I feel so demotivated now, SE overtime has become an unwelcoming place in general.