# Who is 'Monica' and why should we support her (changed user names with added 'support Monica')

Tags: discussion

This has nothing to do with traveling, just as 'supports Monica' has nothing to do with traveling, but I have noticed in the last days many user names suddenly have this extra 'supports Monica' added to it.

Since the added effort in typing (especially on a mobile device) references to user names, this should not be considered off-topic.

It would be better than (for those, such as I, who don't know who the referenced 'Monica' is) as to the reason why should be explained.

- @DavidSupportsMonica
- @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica
- @MarkMayoSupportsMonica

as 2 different samples of Monica based user names

The reason why other users should have to deal with this extra complicated naming convention would also be welcomed.

Freedom of expression is one thing, imposing inconvenience to others (who don't know the reason why) another

---

Unfortunately, moving this topic away from the original forum (where they are effected by the problem) and who do not see this forum is not helpful.

---

The first comment, removed through the move, gives the source of the prrloblem

- [Support of Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)

  - [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)

This information should be made available to those affected by the problem and hidden elsewhere

This should not be closed since the other questions do not address the problem that those affected by the problem don't have the faintest clue what this is about

The danger exists that this may be understood as a form of censorship when efforts are made to insure that those effected, remain uninformed

---

After a swift reading of the [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it), I at least have an idea about what this matter is about, which was the main purpose of the question

However, the extreme, aggressive comments made by others, while I was reading it, makes me appreciate more Chanceller[in]'s Merkel's statement from yesterday (2019-11-09) better:

> the values on which EU is founded - freedom, democracy, equality, rule of law, human rights - they are anything but self-evident and they have to be revitalised and defended time and time again

Those that made those comments, should think about that aspect.

---

Comment: Note that it is "Monica" not "Monika".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan hopefully all corrected (in my language a 'k' is used)

Comment: On the top right of every page there's a yellow box with links. Explains all!

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Sorry, on the top right of this page there is no yellow box with links, thus nothing is is  explained. I don't have the fantest clue of what the purpose of your comment means. Kindly refrain from expressing yourself that is dependent on the computer display that **you** but other do not.

Comment: @simonatrcl What **proof** do you have that I and others are not effected (with source please)? And as a German I know that Bernhard (as a German name) is spelled such. I am also aware that else where it is spelled otherwise. I also assume in *your* country it is common that claims being made by person who cannot prove that these claims are true are convicted by a judge for **slander**.

Comment: Affected vs effected: I effected a change but it did not affect me; he effected a change and it affected me greatly!. Also, slander requires rather more than an incorrect claim (IANAL but this applies pretty much everywhere in the world that I am aware of); this is just as well as if not then your last sentence is probably slanderous. (PS Neither your nor any sentence of mine here is slanderous: they were not spoken publicly. Libel is the word you're looking for, but they aren't libellous either.)

Comment: If,you use the desktop version of the site, which I do even on my mobile device, you can type the first letter or two and then tap the suggested username and not have to type it.

Comment: @phoog On my Nexus 7 there is no 'tab' key to use (that I know of), which has often lead to misstyping in the past. The tooltip that shows up cannot always be selected to fill out the user name.

Comment: I'm sorry. I see so many links (mostly unrelated to the current post) on the right side of every page of the StackeExchange network, that I trusted everybody does.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Ah, now I understand. On my machine you have to scroll down to the end to see that list (Linked, Related), which I rarely due. In this case that wouldn't have helped since 'Monica' as part of the user name would not be related to a question or answer.

Comment: Even on mobile, you can type as few as three characters of the username to ping.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work.  So usernames that are long, for whatever reason, needn't seriously inconvenience you.

Comment: I have to assume that the downvotes are from people who don't want anyone to know why we are supporting Monica.

Answer (score 7):

> Unfortunately, moving this topic away from the original forum (where they are effected by the problem) and who do not see this forum is not helpful.

This forum is for discussing things about the site, so this is the best site for this question.

If users are interested, they can see that [Support of Monica](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/support-of-monica?cb=1) is featured and appears in the right-box.

Also visible on mobile:

[image]

Comment: On my machine, this dialog turns up where you have to page down to an area (that I at least) rarely page down to.